# Can I show clients I've worked with at my agency on my personal portfolio site?

Tags: freelance-websites, portfolio

I'm an art director working at a design and marketing agency for about a year now and I'm not planning on leaving soon. I also do freelance work on the side, and I'm updating my website. Can I feature some of the clients I've done design work for at my agency on my site, as long as I credit my agency and the team in the individual projects?

**I'm not asking about the work itself,** because I won't list any work I haven't talked to my agency about to make sure. **Just asking about the ability to list the client logos as clients I've worked with**, so there aren't any contract issues I can think of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use screenshots of my development works in a huge organization in my personal portfolio?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2264/can-i-use-screenshots-of-my-development-works-in-a-huge-organization-in-my-perso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the agency and the client. If they both say yes, then you're good. If not, then you can't put the projects in your portfolio.

Answer (score 4):

No — this may seem to a large extent both unhealthy and unethical in my humble opinion.

You've worked for the agency and as such can have this reflected in your CV, with your core duties and responsibilities, without exposing any customer information or claiming direct/indirect credit for a specific product/services unless with express written permission/approval.

You need to understand that your agency (as you currently still work there) **is a company**, with individual and corporate competitors.

Leaving your company to then compete against it, using that company's product(s) as leverage (mentioning you were a part of that project); what message are you trying to send? And would it be you as an individual, or your new company you'd be attributing this to?

I recommend you focus on your personal achievements as a freelancer for your portfolio for better and brighter prospects, rather than morally conflicting ones.

Comment: That's good feedback. There wouldn't be a conflict of interests competitively in the sense that I'm an individual freelance designer and my agency only works with multibillion dollar companies.

Comment: I understand you @Peacockerie. Having read your comment and recent post update, I still recommend you **do not** (not even use the logo of companies the agency where you've once/still works delivered). Whether any of such companies knows you as an individual having worked on such projects or not, it is still not the best. Just stay away from that. You may find this [post](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/a/2272/15276) helpful as well.

Comment: That post only mentions it shouldn't be done for NDA purposes, which do not apply when the clients themselves are publicly acknowledged by the employer for which that work was done. I think the difference is going to be in the way the clients are presented, either as "my clients" or "people I've worked with".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but normally you would mention that in your contract with your client.  If it was not in your original contract with your client, I would recommend asking the client (in writing or email) as a courtesy. Most of the time, they will say yes.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but explain that you were working within a particular team or as a member of the agency. Other than that you should obviously only share content that you're contractually allowed to share with regards to that agencies policies.