# Site created for agency...can I show it in my portfolio?

Tags: contracts, legal, attracting-clients, portfolio

Previously my agency have created few websites for a marketing agency.
They put their site link on these sites: "Site by "

Can we put these sites created, in my  agency portfolio?
There is no NDA signed between us and marketing agency.

Also, what will potential client think if the site is in my agency portfolio and there is "Site by " on it?

Please advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I show clients I've worked with at my agency on my personal portfolio site?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/can-i-show-clients-ive-worked-with-at-my-agency-on-my-personal-portfolio-site)

Comment: No. It is not. I have edited the question. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: I fail to see how it's different.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a portfolio, you want to make sure you get credit for what you have done, and it's very important to not take credit of someone elses work. You need to decide what area or what percentage of what you are showcasing was created by you. You may need to clarify "all images on this website was created by me", or "all mark up and javascript was written by me" so that people know what you are responsible for.

The agency will only be annoyed if you tried to take credit for their/someone elses work.
If you have a contract, check to see what the contract says regarding this area.